# iOS 8 self sizing cells with changing height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I created a tableview with self-sizing UITableViewCells using

`tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

For testing a created a single `UIView` and added it to `cell.contentView` with the following constraints. (using masonry)

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    UIView *superview = self.contentView;

    if (!_didSetupConstraints) {
        [self.testView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(superview);
            make.height.equalTo(@10.0f);
            make.left.equalTo(superview);
            make.right.equalTo(superview);
            make.bottom.equalTo(superview);
        }];

        _didSetupConstraints = YES;
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

When i select a row i like to change the height of the selected cell. I do this by:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    [self.testView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        if (selected) {
            make.height.equalTo(@100);
        }
        else {
            make.height.equalTo(@10);
        }
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [super layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

It seems to work but, xcode complaints with the following error:

`Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`

Then problem is that `contentView` is creating a height constaint on its own (because `contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;` per default).

So when updateConstraints is first run, the system will create a height constraint on `contentView` equal to `10.0f`

afterwards when `setSelected...` is called i alter the height of my `testView` so theres a conflict between `testView.height` (100.0f) and `contentView.height` (10.0f) and since `testView` is attached to the bottom of `contentView` (in order for self-sizing cells to work) it gives and error.

I tried setting `contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` but then it seems the UITableViewCell cant really figure out a proper size for the cell. (sometimes it too wide / too small) etc.

What is the proper way to implement self-sizing cells which can have their height changed dynamicly?

Comment: Did you set the `estimatedRowHeight` property?

Comment: I did not set estimatedRowHeight :) but just tested and it does not have any effect on the issue with conflicting height constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

**1. The AutoLayout message: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`**

This is caused by the fact that you update your custom view's `height` constraint, but you do not update the `contentView`'s `height` constraint. Because you also set the custom view's `bottom` constraint to the contentView `bottom`, the system cannot satisfy both contstraints: The custom view cannot have a height of 100 and at the same time be connected to the contentView's bottom while the contentView still has a height of 10.

The fix for this is quite easy. You define a height constraint for the contentView and set it to the height of your custom view:

```
[self.contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.height.equalTo(self.testView);
}];
```

This fixes the problem.

**2. Updating the cell's height**

Updating the cell height is not so easy because the cell heights are handled by the `UITableViewController` and not the cells themselves. Of course you can change the height of your cell, but as long as the `UITableViewController` does not give the cell enough space you won't see the new cell height. You will see that your now higher cell will overlap the next cell.

So you need a way to tell the `UITableViewController` that it should update the height of your cell. You can do that by calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. That reloads the cell and also animates it nicely. So the cell somehow has to call that method on the `UITableViewController`. The challenge there: A `UITableViewCell` has no reference to its `UITableViewController` (and it shouldn't).

What you can do is subclass `UITableViewCell` and give it a closure property that it can execute whenever its height has changed:

```
class DynamicHeightTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var heightDidChange: (() -> Void)?
    ...
```

Now, when you dequeue a cell in your `UITableViewControllerDataSource` you set its closure:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DynamicHeightTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let customCell = cell as? DynamicHeightTableViewCell {
        customCell.heightDidChange = { [weak cell, weak tableView] in
            if let currentIndexPath = tableView?.indexPathForCell(cell!) {
                tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([currentIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

And then when the cell changes its height you just execute the closure and the cell will be reloaded:

```
func theFunctionWhereTheHeightChanges() {

   // change the height

   heightDidChange?()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me (a crash can occur on the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths) and the constraint linking the testView to the contentView can trigger Autolayout conflict too.